# element.offset().top; not working properly to pull scroll when in the middle of a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

As of right now I've spent a few hours trying to figure out and read this code that was provided to me.  It is somewhat difficult to get the code to glitch out...  if you check out this page right here:
http://www.1stamender.com/article.php?articlenumber=1125

There is a portion of the page that says: "You may also like" held within a container with the class 'follow-scroll'.  Basically if you reload the page (hard refresh ctrl + f5) halfway down it will not pull the element.offset properly and either be too low or too high. (also happens when you resize the page)  If I could get some help with this code I would appreciate it greatly! I cannot seem to read this jquery/javascript properly as I mainly work PHP and SQL.  It is also very very easy to see broken on mobile applications either due to bootstrap or the way it detects the offset y.
Here is the code for it:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var element = $('.follow-scroll');
    var originalY = element.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 40;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 0);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried fixing this first before proceeding with a solution? https://www.screencast.com/t/0IBU2jE5JhrO

Comment: woops my fault was messing around with my scripts earlier and didn't put that back. Made the change.

Comment: try to use a debugger and autorespond the page to prevent you from messing up the live page. Try to use fiddler

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($(window).outerHeight()+$(window).scrollTop()) >= $('.follow-scroll').offset().top)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Oh man close I do love your solution to ignore the script unless it meets the credentials. I did try this and unfortunately it still causes the same issue when performing a hard refresh about a quarter the way into the page...

Comment: there is problem in css instead

Comment: @Roljhon is it ok now?

Comment: I uploaded the code from this provided answer. I can't make heads or tails of it. I am using google chrome on a desktop. doing a hard refresh causes the issue to occur.

Comment: @sblumberg your heading should be inside the class "follow-scroll"

Comment: @sblumberg did you got it !!

Comment: @Anonymous I am not sure what you mean by heading should be inside the class "follow-scroll".

Comment: @sblumberg the text "you may also like" should be inside the class "follow-scroll"